# Select 2 no bootstrap 3

Tags: php, laravel, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-select2

Existe alguma forma de utilizar o select2 no Bootstrap 3.3, terial algum exemplo pra min tentar implementar, estou construindo meu TCC em cima do template adminLTE e precisava de algo como ele em algumas consultas, desde já agradeço!

Consegui implementar assim:

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
      <label class="required-inputs"><b>Descrição</b></label>
      <select id="select2-ex" name="state" style="width: 100%;">
           @foreach($professores as $p)
                <option value="{{$p->id}}">{{$p->nome}}</option>
           @endforeach
       </select></div>
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#select2-ex').select2();
});
```

Como posso retornar mais de um item?

Comment: https://fk.github.io/select2-bootstrap-css/

Comment: Ok vc precisa fazer com o select2? Selecionar mais de um item de uma vez?

Comment: Isso conseguir implementar, como posso selecionar mais de um item

Comment: Você chegou a olhar a [documentação](https://select2.org/getting-started/basic-usage)? lá tem exemplos de como implementar

Comment: Consegui encontrar na documentação, valeu!!